# Want to achieve functionality by using Javascripts map,reduce,foreach,filter methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, reduce

Please help me to write better code.

Suppose I have a JavaScript array like below:

```
var students = [
    { firstname: "stud1", lastname: "stud2", marks: "60" },
    { firstname: "stud3", lastname: "stud4", marks: "30" },
    { firstname: "stud5", lastname: "stud6", marks: "70" },
    { firstname: "stud7", lastname: "stud8", marks: "55" },
    { firstname: "stud9", lastname: "stud10", marks: "20" },
];
```

On page I want to show data in two parts, 1)Students who got marks >= 40 2)Students who got marks < 40

By using for loop I done this functionality easily as below.

```
var data = "";var data1 = "";
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++ )
{
    if(students.marks >= 40){
        data += = students.firstname + " " + students.lastname; //actual data in html div tag
        ....
    }else{
            data1 += = students.firstname + " " + students.lastname;
    }
}
```

I want to achieve same functionality by using JavaScript methods like map, reduce, foreach, filter etc. (want to improve my JavaScript knowledge)

Don't know exactly which method is useful for such functionality.

Used map method and tried to display data, but there is a trailing , at the end of each object/array.

Can anyone please help/guide me to write proper code?

Comment: do you like to use only one loop, or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution using `filter` and `forEach` methods, using `callback` functions.

See references here :

- [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var students = [
    { firstname: "stud1", lastname: "stud2", marks: "60" },
    { firstname: "stud3", lastname: "stud4", marks: "30" },
    { firstname: "stud5", lastname: "stud6", marks: "70" },
    { firstname: "stud7", lastname: "stud8", marks: "55" },
    { firstname: "stud9", lastname: "stud10", marks: "20" },
];
students.filter(function(item){
    return item.marks>=40;  
}).forEach(function(item){
    div=document.getElementById('persons');
    div.innerHTML+=item.firstname+' '+item.lastname+'<br>';
});
```

```html
<div id="persons"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Alexandru, I gone through your code. filtered variable now contain array and I can split those array and display data (students name) on screen. But again I have to right split and for..loop. Can I format a string (data) in proper way and give back to div's innerHtml property via map method only? pls look below code.
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = persons.map(showData);
    function showData(item, index) {
        var sDiv = "";
        var fullname = [item.firstname, item.lastname].join(" ");
        sDiv += String(fullname) + "<br />";
        return sDiv;
    }

Comment: for what you want you need `forEach` function..I will update my code in few moments.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks Alexandru!! You gave answer but still have few questions. Before your answer what I tried is:
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = students.forEach(showDataByForeach);
    function showDataByForeach(item) {
        var sDiv = "";
        sDiv += item.firstname + "<br />";
        return sDiv;
    }
but this won't work. even I tried to pass item to function showDataByForeach like below but that also wont work.
.forEach(showDataByForeach(item))
May I know my mistake/what I did wrong. Thanks

Comment: Your code didn't work because `forEach` function calls a provided function once for each element in your array. Callback function is applied for every element from your array and you have to create your string during `iterating` all elements. Use this code: `var str=""; students.forEach(showDataByForeach); function showDataByForeach(item) { str+=item.firstname+"<br>"; } document.getElementById('persons').innerHTML=str;`

Comment: Thanks Alexandru!! Thanks for your help. Learn many things today. Will study further to understand it properly. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop and add the information with `predicate` as index. Later join the elements for getting a sting for each element.

```js
var students = [{ firstname: "stud1", lastname: "stud2", marks: "60" }, { firstname: "stud3", lastname: "stud4", marks: "30" }, { firstname: "stud5", lastname: "stud6", marks: "70" }, { firstname: "stud7", lastname: "stud8", marks: "55" }, { firstname: "stud9", lastname: "stud10", marks: "20" }], 
    predicate = function (o) { return o.marks >= 40; },
    result = [[], []];      

students.forEach(function (a) {
    result[+predicate(a)].push(a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastname);
});
result = result.map(function (a) { return a.join(', '); });

console.log(result);
```